# MethodError: no method matching Weights(::Array{Any,1}, ::Float64)

Tags: arrays, julia, sample

I’m trying to do a sample of a string array, incorporating weights for each of the elements of the array. Specifically,

```
new_name_event = sample(events,Weights(dict_betas_choices[string(new_player)][new_zone][string(new_time)][string(new_loc)][string(new_res)]))

>ERROR:
MethodError: no method matching Weights(::Array{Any,1}, ::Float64)
Closest candidates are:
  Weights(!Matched::var"#18#V", ::var"#16#S") where {var"#16#S"<:Real, var"#17#T"<:Real, var"#18#V"<:AbstractArray{var"#17#T",1}} at C:\Users\semed\.julia\packages\StatsBase\ZxhK8\src\weights.jl:13
  Weights(::Any) at C:\Users\semed\.julia\packages\StatsBase\ZxhK8\src\weights.jl:16

Stacktrace:
 [1] Weights(::Array{Any,1}) at C:\Users\semed\.julia\packages\StatsBase\ZxhK8\src\weights.jl:16
 [2] top-level scope at .\In[22]:62
 [3] include_string(::Function, ::Module, ::String, ::String) at .\loading.jl:1091
```

Where,

```
println(events, typeof(events))
>["Shot", "Duel", "Pass"]Array{String,1}

pesos = dict_betas_choices[string(new_player)][new_zone][string(new_time)][string(new_loc)][string(new_res)]
println(pesos, typeof(pesos), typeof(pesos[1]))
>Any[0.00114591, 0.69774462, 0.30110947] Array{Any,1} Float64
```

Answer (score 4):

This should fix it in your case:

```
Float64.(dict_betas_choices[string(new_player)][new_zone][string(new_time)][string(new_loc)][string(new_res)])
```

If it errors it would mean that your data are not consisting of only numbers.

In general you should fix the data in the source to have `eltype` not `Any` but some real number type, e.g. `Float64` as suggested above (this should be fixed at data structure creation time).